# Suppress all output of knitr when knitting a file

Tags: r, knitr

I am using knitr and would like to suppress any kind of verbose output when knitting a file.
I know that I can remove the progress bar by

```
opts_knit$set(progress=FALSE)
```

Yet, I would like to suppress even the info about the processing file and the output file.
Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just added a new argument named [`quiet`](https://twitter.com/xieyihui/status/316669228415610880) in `knit()` the other day, which will suppress the messages about filenames. You can install the [latest development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme), or wait for `knitr` v1.2 which is about 10 days away.

```
library(knitr)
knit(..., quiet = TRUE)
```

Comment: just tried to install knitr devel under R devel (2013-02-27 r62087),I get the following error:

    ** installing vignettes
    Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'knitr', details:
      call: tools::vignetteEngine("knitr", weave = vweave,    tangle=     vtangle, 
  error: unused arguments (pattern = c("[.][rRsS](nw|tex)$", "[.][Rr](md|html)$"), package = pkg)
ERROR: installing vignettes failed.


Its working fine under R 3.0.0 beta, do I just have to use a more recent R devel?

Comment: @steffi If you use R-devel, you have to check out at least r62130; 62087 is not sufficient.